# Angular 9 PWA: Service Worker / Manifest scope issues when running app in subdirectory and service worker hosted in a different subdirectory

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 to host and serve everything. "index.html" is not intended to be accessed directly, "/app" hits an endpoint in .net core that serves the index.html file

1. Angular 9 with PWA
2. Running app at https://example.com/app
3. Service worker and assets are stored at https://example.com/dist/assets
4. Scope of service worker was set to "/"
5. manifest scope set to "/" and start_url set to "index.html"

Problems:

1. Service worker is trying to cache assets at root: https://example.com/index.html. SHOULD BE https://example.com/dist/assets/index.html
2. I tried catching this on the server, and setting 301 permanent redirect to the correct asset
3. The problem is, I also have an endpoint Home/Logout which the service worker is trying to serve up
4. I also have code on the backend that, instead of serving a 404 for unfound paths, it just serves the result of hitting /app
5. If you access index.html but you are not logged in, it tries redirecting you to Home/Logout
6. The service worker seems to think Home/Logout should be serving the content for index.html
7. You end up in this crazy infinite redirect loop

So, the root problem has to do with the app running at /app instead of /, and potentially having all of my assets at /dist/assets instead of /.

I need the PWA to be installable from my landing page, located at /, but the start_url would ideally be "/app", but as long as it is the index.html file that is fine

Is there any configuration changes I could make, or any .net core changes I could make, to support this?

Also, I did not install the pwa with a basehref parameter if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. You want to build with --baseRef=/your/sub/directory/here/
2. You want your manifest file to have scope="." and start_url="./"
3. You need to update your ngsw-config.json file.
4. That means, add navigationUrls property, include everything angular provides in stock form, then add rules to EXCLUDE specific urls.
5. Angular provides the following in stock form:

```html
    [
      '/**',           
      '!/**/*.*',      
      '!/**/*__*',     
      '!/**/*__*/**',  
    ]
```

6. In my case, I needed to exclude urls that contain "Home". But, there doesn't seem to be a glob pattern I can use that works with angular's compiler. So, I wrote a deploy step that merges a custom configuration with the configuration that angular compiles.

```html
        public static void Execute()
        {
            Log.Info("Configuring ngsw.json");
            var ngsw = System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"{DeploySettings.SourcePath}wwwroot/dist/assets/ngsw.json");

            var ngswJson = JObject.Parse(ngsw);
            var toMerge = JObject.Parse(@"{
                                            ""navigationUrls"":[
                                                {
                                                  ""positive"": false,
                                                  ""regex"": ""^.*Home.*$""
                                                }

                                             ]}");
            ngswJson.Merge(toMerge);

            var json = ngswJson.ToString();

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText($"{DeploySettings.SourcePath}wwwroot/dist/assets/ngsw.json", json);
        }
```

At this point, I just have to figure out how to exclude my landing page and we'll be good. My app works offline finally!

Comment: can you please help with this one? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016452/angular-9-pwa-social-login-redirects-issue-on-start-url-index-page